# powershell substring method not found

Tags: powershell

```
$computername = 'RSERV1234'    
$computername.Substring(5,4) returns '1234' as expected    
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -like $computername.Substring(5,4)}
```

returns:

```
Property 'Substring' not found in object of type: 'System.String'
```

Please help!

Comment: Method calls are not supported as comparison arguments inside the Active Directory filter, causing PowerShell to ignore the `(5,4)` part and look for a property called `Substring` - which doesn't exist. Call `Substring()` before `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`

Comment: Try: `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -like "*$($computername.Substring(5,4))*"}`

Answer (score 1):

From [`about_ActiveDirecory_Filter`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527(v=ws.10).aspx):

```
Filter Syntax
  The following syntax descriptions use Backus-Naur form to show the
  PowerShell Expression Language for the Filter parameter.

    <filter>  ::= "{" <FilterComponentList> "}"

    <FilterComponentList> ::= <FilterComponent> |
        <FilterComponent> <JoinOperator> <FilterComponent> |
        <NotOperator>  <FilterComponent>

    <FilterComponent> ::= <attr> <FilterOperator> <value> |
        "(" <FilterComponent> ")"

    <FilterOperator> ::= "-eq" | "-le" | "-ge" | "-ne" | "-lt" | "-gt" |
        "-approx" | "-bor" | "-band" | "-recursivematch" | "-like" |
        "-notlike"

    <JoinOperator> ::= "-and" | "-or"

    <NotOperator> ::= "-not"

    <attr> ::= <PropertyName> | <LDAPDisplayName of the attribute>

    <value>::= < this value will be compared to the object data for
        attribute <ATTR> using the specified filter operator
```

The `Filter` parameter translates PowerShell-like expressions to an LDAP filter, but doesn't support just any arbitrary PowerShell statement, only a specific set of comparison operations with attribute names as the left-hand operand and the comparison value on the right hand side.

Do your `Substring()` call beforehand:

```
$substr = $computername.Substring(5,4)

Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -like "$substr"}
```

Comment: Great thanks, wanted to pipeline the computername in but thanks anyway